# Visual Studio Build Errors not in UI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio has been giving me strange build errors for a "compiler" I'm making for class.  It's telling me the .cpp functions "is not a member of its [mother function in the header]," "unknown override specifiers" for declared header functions, saying certain functions don't take a [this] amount of arguments...etc.  The weird thing is, although it points to certain lines, there are no error marks *anywhere*.  No squiggly lines of any color.  The syntax seems correct regardless of UI.  All the errors are build errors--nothing from Intellisense.

My only guess is perhaps an #include or inheritance issue, so I'm giving the organization of my code to give you an idea (showing you the code itself is useless since there are no syntax errors that the UI shows).

If it means anything, I have transferred text files in between Linux and Windows (what I'm using this on currently).  For your reference, I have tried clearing of project caches, rebuilding and restarting the project, and even copying to a new project with no change in the errors.  It's the newest update of VS2017 from this year. Something about the includes is my guess, but if not, VS seems to be the culprit.  But let me know of possibilities.

main.cpp:

```
//#pragma once
#include "DatalogProgram.h"
#include "Scanner.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main() {
    string filepath = "";
    Scanner sc;

    DatalogProgram parser;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Scanner.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Token.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

class Scanner {};
```

DatalogProgram.h:

```
#pragma once
#include "Scanner.h"

class DatalogProgram {};
```

Token.h:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

enum Toktype {};

class Token {};
```

Comment: You don't need any `#pragma once` in your main.cpp file...

Comment: Point taken, and edited.  But it doesn't change my issue...

Comment: WFM (Visual Studio 2017 15.5.4), must be a part of code/setup you're not showing.

Comment: I would show the code, but I don't know how much it helps.  e.g., bool Scanner::scan(string filename)  gets an error: "overloaded member function not found in Scanner," even though bool scan(string filename) is in Scanner.h.  I don't know what would be helpful to show...brackets close classes/functions correctly too.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a circular include problem (`a.h` includes `b.h` and `b.h` includes `a.h`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue--yes, it was in my code.  I didn't do "std::" before the string and fstream references, which threw all the "doesn't recognize" problems.  Once I did that and realigned the #include chain, it worked perfectly.  If I showed some code, y'all probably would've caught it faster.